# SQLite database: Writing and reading data between multiple activities within Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity

Using Android studio and the SQLite database:

I have an activity which populates a SQLite database with a few data types per entry.

I want to be able to have another activity that can read this data however, I am not sure how to access the same database via another activity. At the moment I'm not sure if I should pass it as a bundle or whether there is access method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some code examples of how you are currently adding data to the SQLite Database as there are a number of different ways of doing this and this affects how you would access it in another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a new class eg:- Data

create `public static String userid;` in it

then use `Data.userid = sqlitedata` and then you can use `Data.userid` anywhere in your project it will return the same value...

Comment: Cheers for this is helped a lot. I had to make my SQL database helper a public static variable. This then enabled me to import the database within the other activity for use.

Answer (score 0):

That's super easy.

Let's say this is your database defined this way if you use Room library.

```
@Database(
entities = [UserSchema::class],
version = 1,
exportSchema = false)

abstract class UserDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract  fun userDoa(): UserDao

companion object {
    private var instance: UserDatabase? = null
    fun getInstance(context: Context): UserDatabase? {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(LmdDatabase::class) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    UserDatabase::class.java,
                    Constants.USER_DATABASE
                ).addMigrations()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
            }
        }
        return instance
    }

    fun destroyInstance() {
        instance?.close()
        instance = null
    }
}
}
```

Here is your user entity definition:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class UserSchema(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id") val userId:String
)
```

Here is your doa to delete and remove user objects from database

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(vararg userSchema: UserSchema)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(vararg userSchema: UserSchema)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<UserSchema>>
}
```

Your first activity can call insert from coroutine context to insert data e.g user into table using `suspend insert` method. The other activity can observe that table or database for data change using `getAll()` method